# What is the -> (dash greater than) operator in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just ran across the following line of code in a Rails app:

```
scope :for_uid, ->(external_id) { where(external_id: external_id) }
```

What does the `->` operator mean? It's kind of hard to Google.

Comment: It's called "stabby lambda". Just FYI.

Comment: @fotanus - Thanks, I just didn't know what to search for and most search engines ignore the -> in the search terms.

Comment: There's always [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+-%3E) but that's not terribly useful in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is syntactic sugar.

```
->(external_id) { where(external_id: external_id) }
```

is equal to:

```
lambda { |external_id| where(external_id: external_id) }
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it looked familiar. I just didn't know what to search for to find it.

Comment: Ah! Did they steal this from CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 7):

It's [new lambda notation](https://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&q=new%20lambda%20notation%20ruby&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#client=opera&hs=xn5&channel=suggest&sclient=psy-ab&q=new%20lambda%20syntax%20ruby&oq=new%20lambda%20syntax%20ruby&gs_l=serp.3..0i7j0i7i30j0i8i30l2.3192.3760.0.4052.6.5.0.0.0.3.151.506.3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.h9QWtLKyxDQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.Yms&fp=de539b05590e75ed&biw=1918&bih=1001). This syntax was introduced in ruby 1.9, and is used to define unnamed functions.

In your example it is scope defined by unnamed function.

Answer (score 5):

The `->` operator was introduced in Ruby 1.9 as a shorthand syntax for the old `lambda` function.  It behaves nearly identically to the `lambda` function but allows you to specify parameters outside the block:

```
lambda {|param| puts param }

# becomes

-> (param) { puts params }
```